# SQL Server 2019 UTF-8 collation & varchar(n)

Tags: sql-server

I use `varchar(n)` data type in many tables in my database.

Is there is a way to specify characters count (as n characters) instead bytes count?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: A workaround is to use types that are "long enough" (at worst a character needs 4 UTF-8 bytes to be encoded, though most need less) and use a `CHECK` constraint on the length if you need to enforce a maximum. This needs some balance because simply multiplying all sizes by 4 may have bad consequences for performance if too much memory is allocated for result sets, so this should only be used if a worst case must be accommodated. Otherwise just sort of eyeball it (or measure it with `DATALENGTH` if you have existing data).

Comment: thanks .can I extend varchar data type in all table and stored procedure automatically or make n in varchar(n) mean 2n bytes instead one byte for some legacy application?